# Remove rows in a data frame until the sum of a column get specific value

Tags: r

I am working in a data frame like this

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
1  2  1  10
1  1  1  50
1  2  2  40
2  1  1  30
3  3  3  80
```

I want to get a new data frame where the sum of values of `c4` is between 60 and 100, in this case the sum is 210, then the new data frame must have a structure like this:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
1  2  1  10
1  1  1  50
1  2  2  40
```

You can note that the sum of `c4` is between 60 and 100, and the others raws had been deleted. How can I make this in R. Thanks.

Comment: Please also show us what you have tried.

Comment: Does it have to be the first few rows of your data.frame? Imagine the first two values in `c4` were `50` and `60`, there would be no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
DF[cumsum(DF$c4)<=100,]
```

Where `DF` is your dataframe.